# copy constructor problem while reading an object directly into vector using copy and stream iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

can some body please explain the behavior in the output while running the following code.
I am little confused about number of times the copy constructor getting called.

```
using namespace std;
class A {
    int i;
public:
    A() {
    };
    A(const A& a) {
        i = a.i;
        cout << "copy constructor invoked" << endl;
    };
    A(int num) {
        i = num;
    };
    A& operator = (const A&a) {
        i = a.i;
//      cout << "assignment operator invoked" << endl;
    };
    ~A() {
        cout << "destructor called" << endl;
    };
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream & out, const A& a);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &in, A&a);
};

ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const A& a) {
    out << a.i;
    return out;
}

istream & operator >> (istream & in, A&a) {
    in >> a.i;
    return in;

}
int main() {
    vector<A> vA;
    copy(istream_iterator<A>(cin), istream_iterator<A>(), back_inserter(vA));
//  copy(vA.begin(), vA.end(), ostream_iterator<A>(cout, "\t"));
    return 0;
}
```

The output observed is

```
ajay@ubuntu:~/workspace/ostream_iterator/src$ ./a.out 
40
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
ajay@ubuntu:~/workspace/ostream_iterator/src$
```

I thought the copy constructor would be called once while inserting into the vector, as containers stores objects by values.

Comment: Have you tried turning on the optimizations?

Comment: even with level 3 optimization i am getting same no of copy construtor calls, and i am using gcc version 4.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

The copy constructor should be called at least 3 times:

- 1 copy per `istream_iterator` passed to `std::copy`, as
  `istream_iterator` stores a local
  value of the parameterized type and
  most likely copies it in its copy
  constructor and they are passed by
  value to `std::copy`. (2)
- 1 to insert into `vector<A> vA` via `vA.push_back(...)`, called by
  the `back_inserter(vA)` assignment
  operator. (3)

The compiler can probably optimize out a few of those copies, but where the other 8 come from is a mystery to me.

EDIT: Incidentally, I get 8 calls to the copy constructor running on codepad.org: http://codepad.org/THFGFCCk

EDIT2: When I ran this with VS2008, I got 7 calls to the copy constructor. The additional 4 were the result of copying around the input iterators to `std::copy` for bounds checking in a debug build. When running in a fully optimized build, I only get 3 calls to the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The istream_iterator is getting built and copied a bunch of times.  Here's my output:

```
40
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
destructor called
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
destructor called
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
copy constructor invoked
```